# How to prevent remove objectbox db from clear app cache

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, objectbox

I use the ObjectBox in my kotlin project. Users can erase the database by clearing the application Data from the Android settings. 
I want to prevent database removal or change ObjectBox Store mode to SQLite!

thanks

Comment: application "cache" or "data"?

Comment: hi, application data!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to make user data persistent you definitely should save and check DB copy on your server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you probably know, this is "normal" behavior on Android. When you delete an app's data, you have to start from scratch. E.g. all local data lost and log-in again etc. I'd guess that 0.01% of users would actually know about it and actually do that.

Anyway, yes, the question is if you want to extend data scope to cloud/server... That's a different topic though. ObjectBox will offer data synchronization later this year.

Alternatively, there's also Android's backup function: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

Comment: "this is "normal" behavior on Android"!!, SQLite DB not deleted after clean application data! , but objectBox has been losing data

Comment: You have tested this, yes?

Comment: yeah, I test it

Comment: "Files in the directory returned by `getDatabasePath(String)`, which also includes files created with the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class" might have been automatically backed up by Android. Did you test this on an emulator without a signed in Google account?
You can try including the ObjectBox database file in a manual backup config:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#Files